# Automata Theory - Designing a Non-deterministic Finite automata

Tags: automata, finite-automata

I have been combing through youtube looking for a simple explanation on how to "crack" the "NFA" myth. Please help. Since drawing the schematic can be cumbersome, if you can show me how I can derive the transition states, I will be able to draw the schematic (that I am ok with).

Question:

- Draw Non-deterministic Finite automata that will accept {ab, ba}

==============================================

**The above was the question: The scan below is the original question from a textbook - and I only wanted to know part 1 of the question. Let me know if this is still not clear**.
[image]

Comment: "NFA myth"? Whatever are you talking about?

Comment: The automata should accept **only** $\{ab,ba\}$?

Answer (score 4):

You'll need a start state that can lead into two paths, one of which accepts $ab$, the other of which accepts $ba$. You should be able to construct a NFA from that; I'm not sure what the "NFA myth" is.

Answer (score 2):

Try this automata, it is deterministic and this is a private case of non deteministic , so it is also non deteministic by defenition that  accepts the language $\mathcal L=\{ab,ba\}$

[image]

Comment: It's actually not a DFA, as it doesn't have an $a$ transition from $q_1$, a $b$ transition from $q_2$, or any transitions from $q_3, q_4$. Of course it *is* an NFA, but it's deterministic.

Comment: @BrianO you saying that "it is *not* a **D**eterministuc**FA**....but it is deterministic "

Comment: Yes I'm saying exactly that. It's a technicality. The transition function of a DFA is a *total* function, not a partial function, on $Q\times \Sigma$.

Comment: @BrianO I edited, I'm with my phone

Comment: OK, that's certainly a DFA. You didn't really have to add the trap state — OP just asked for an NFA.

Comment: You can also take $q_3 = q_4$ and save a state. Not that it really matters...